# Closing/restarting Activities in TabHost

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I'm developing an Android 2.3.3 application which consists of a top-level TabActivity. I'm also adding a number of tabs to the TabHost programatically and giving each one a separate child Activity:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyFirstActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(...).setIndicator(...).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MySecondActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(...).setIndicator(...).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

An event happens elsewhere in my application and in response I want to re-create all the tab activities. To do this I'm calling getTabHost().clearAllTabs(), and although it removes them from the tab it doesn't appear to actually kill the activity. If I run the above code again the existing activities are simply added back to their tabs and they continue running as before.

Is there a flag or something I need to set when I create the intents so that they get properly closed and created again? Alternatively is there any other way for the child activities to tell when they're being removed from the parent TabActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restart the Activity by setting flag. The code is as below.

```
    spec = tabHost  .newTabSpec("tab1")
                    .setIndicator("FirstActivity")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this,MyFirstActivity.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: Thanks Raju. I did actually see that flag in the docs but I completely misread what it was for; for some reason I thought it cleared the entire activity stack. Thanks for the help!